# How to remove all iframe using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying it as follows:

```
var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
    iframes[i].parentNode.removeChild(iframes[i]);
}
```

But it only removes one iframe, which parameter should I add to remove all iframes.

Testing: https://jsfiddle.net/yaub8qdr/

Comment: I am honestly not using that function in my code, my code and the one in the upvote response is very different from the linked source.

Comment: There is an additional link added, which I think is more appropriate.

Comment: @Ivar I agree, although the question is closed, the title is more striking even a specific topic, surely other people will observe.

Comment: Your question can serve [as a signpost](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate the array index from the last to first.

```
var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
for (var i = iframes.length - 1; i>=0; i--) {
    iframes[i].parentNode.removeChild(iframes[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByTagName returns a live list so you need to do it in reverse.

Simpler is to not use a live list

https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/hzsqm2jg/

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('iframe')].forEach(ifr => ifr.remove())
```